# PHP SUM IF Function with column criteria

Tags: php, json

I would like to find a formula that sums all my columns starting with surveydone. In my example I have 10 columns starting with surveydone. Could please help me to find this formula ? Thank you

Please find below the echo json_encode I have in PHP :

```
{"id":"7","username":"Thomas","survey1":"valide","surveytoken1":"EuLwfqJI5UYLgK2LQ7jS","surveytokenvalid1":"1","surveydone1":"1","surveytoken2":"EuLwfqJI5UYLgK2LQ7jS","surveytokenvalid2":"1","surveydone2":"1" [...] "surveytokenvalid10":"1","surveydone10":"1"}
```

and here is my code in php:

```
   $user_username = $_SESSION['auth']->username;
   $user['username'] = $user_username;       
   $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE (username = ?)');
   $req->execute([$user_username]);
   $surveyuser = $req->fetch();
   echo json_encode($surveyuser);
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in SQL? `SELECT surveydone1 + surveydone2 + surveydon3 + ... AS surveytotal FROM data`

Comment: why not loop trough and look for sub string of the key?

Comment: This suggests poor data normalization. It would be better to have each survey count in a separate row in the table.

Comment: Then you could do `SELECT SUM(surveydone) FROM data WHERE username = ?`

Comment: 110% agree with the comment regarding normalisation. Normalise it by seperating User and Survey into their own tables and then have a many-to-many relation between the 2 tables by creating a lookup table in the middle. Once you've done that you'll only ever have to query the lookup table which will be highly optimised, especially if you get the correct index setup.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and answers. But it was not my questions. It tried to do it directly in PHP regardless of data normalization. My question was if it is possible to select and sum all columns starting with surveydone in PHP after I have fetched my user from my database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I have managed to found and it works.

```
   $user_username = $_SESSION['auth']->username;
   $user['username'] = $user_username;       
   $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE (username = ?)');
   $req->execute([$user_username]);
   $surveyuser = $req->fetch();
   echo json_encode($surveyuser);

  $surveyuserarray = json_decode(json_encode($surveyuser), True);
  $surveyuser2 = json_encode($surveyuser);

  foreach($surveyuserarray as $key => $value){
    if (strpos($key, 'surveydone') === 0) {
        $only_point[$key] = $value;
       }
   }

  $total_points=array();
  $total_points['totalpoints']=array_sum($only_point);

   echo ($surveyuser2);
   echo json_encode($total_points);
```